# Python Encoding CSV from Windows to linux

Tags: python, pandas

I have a little big problem, we created a `Jupyter` Notebook on windows os, but when I try to run it on a linux server, the following line of code runs without errors: `pandas.read_csv("file.csv", encoding='utf-8')`, but the `NaN` values are not replaced like in windows. Do you know any solution to this issue?

Comment: Could you provide a couple of  lines from the csv file?  Specifically lines that container `NaN`values.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as a clear description of the problem.

Comment: sounds like you want the pandas `fillna()` function, but without an example it's hard to be sure. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution on colab:

pandas.read_csv("file.csv", delimiter='\t', header=None, names=['colNamesHere'])

the solution was import like normali CSV file but in the method you need to add: delimiter='\t'